# Flash message doesn't work in element or layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cannot get the Flash message to appear in an element or in a layout. However, it works fine in a template.

I have the following code in my element, layout and template:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render();?>
```

When I create an error, it displays fine when called from a view, but it doesn't work from an element or my layout file.

The idea is to load the Flash message on top of a form, that is generated using an element in the left side nav in my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that calling more than one `Flash->render()` clears the session for the other subsequent calls.

I just have to figure out the best way to limit which `Flash->render()` to call. For instance, wrapping the `Flash->render()` in an if statement in my element. There's also the possibility to key individual Flash messages that I'm investigating.

**My solution**

Setting the flash:

```
$this->Flash->error(__('Invalid credentials, try again'), ['key' => 'element']);
```

In my element:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render('element')?>
```

Comment: "it would appear" is a pretty odd way of putting it, it is simply designed to  [delete the message as soon as it is rendered](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FlashHelper.php#L84)

Comment: Sorry, new in the art of Cake and wasn't aware.